# WPF Open new Window and set its property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF Program (I'm using MVVM Pattern) I have a simple button with its command. 
When user click on this button the command execute method is called and a new Window is created.

In this application there are two ways to open this window: left mouse click and shitf + left mouse click on the same button.
The difference is the follow: by left mouse click the "Advanced" tab of my tabcontrol in my window isn't showed, else, by left mouse click + shift the "Advanced" tab is showed.

I have implemented this logic but i think that this isn't the best way to do it. This is the code:

Execute method of my Command:

```
private void OptionsExecute()
    {
        var isAdvancedTabVisibile = false;

        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
        {
            isAdvancedTabVisibile = true;
        }

        _windowFactory.OpenOptionsWindow(isAdvancedTabVisibile);
    }
```

XAML (Using the name of properties):

```
<dx:DXTabControl Margin="5" Name="myTabControl">
     <dx:DXTabItem Header="Avanzate" Name="advanced">
          …
     </dx:DXTabItem>
</dx:DXTabControl>
```

C# utility method to open Window (Following MVVM Pattern):

```
public void OpenOptionsWindow(bool isAdvancedTabVisible)
    {
        OptionsWindow window = new OptionsWindow();
        var tabCollection=window.myTabControl.Items;
        var tabList=tabCollection.Cast<DXTabItem>().ToList();

        if (isAdvancedTabVisible)
        {
            tabList.FirstOrDefault(ti => ti.Name == "advanced").Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            tabList.FirstOrDefault(ti => ti.Name == "advanced").Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

My question is: there is a better way to do the same thing? A way by setting a flag property in my ViewModel and bind the tabitem Visibility to this property? Any other suggestion? 
Thanks.

Comment: by using some framework which would have something like `NavigationService/VisualizerService` which would have method like `Navigate/Show` which take `ViewModel` as parameter

Comment: Can you post any snippets of code please?

Comment: sure for `Catel` it will be `var viewModel = TypeFactory.Default.CreateInstanceWithParametersAndAutoCompletion<OptionsViewModel>(/*parameters go here fx bool advanced*/); await iUIVisualizerService.ShowDialogAsync(viewModel);`

Comment: If you were following MVVM concepts, you would be setting the DataContext of the Window to the ViewModel but I don't see that in your OpenOptionsWindow method. To answer your question: you would set an IsAdvancedTabVisible onto the ViewModel. Then you can bind it from the view as you mentioned.

Comment: In my sample I establish the boolean flag in a ViewModel (called VM1 for example), my OptionsWindow is another Window and its ViewModel is called VM2, so have I to share, for example with IMessage, my property between different ViewModel?